# Laravel 5.1 Session not working outside Route::get

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I have some code like this and working:

```
Route::get('addnew',function(){         
        $user = Users::where('username','=',session('username'))->first();
        $data = $user->toArray();
        return view('layout.addnew')->with($data);
    });
Route::post('addnew', ['uses'=>'UsersController@addnew']);
```

With code above: *session('username')* not null

But, when i use this code like below:

```
$user = Users::where('username','=',session('username'))->first();
$data = $user->toArray();
Route::get('addnew',function() use($data){
        return view('layout.addnew')->with($data);
    });
Route::post('addnew', ['uses'=>'UsersController@addnew']);
```

With code above: *session('username')* null => so *$data* is non-object and code not working.

Somebody help me, please!

Thank you very much!

Comment: its null because what is above the route is not executed thats why, only whats inside will work because thats the route your accessing(i think so)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its better if you do this

**routes.php**

```
  Route::get('/addnew', 'HomeController@addnew');
```

**in the controller** (HomeController in this case which should be there by default)

add this to the controller

```
  public function getuser(){

  return Users::where('username','=',session('username'))->first()->toArray();


 }

public function addnew() {

   return view('layout.addnew')->with('user',$this->getuser());

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i have so much `Route::get` need var `$data`, and i want use code just only one times:`$user = Users::where('username','=',session('username'))->first()->toArray()`

Comment: then you should definitly use a controller , add a method (getuser forexempke)in the controller that returns the data you want $user in this case, and when ever you need that $user in another method you can cet it like this $`user = $this->getuser();`

Comment: I have to comback again to say: **Thank you very very very much**, you saved my project and saved my life.